# Why am I getting error 1054 for this query ? Is there a more efficient way to write this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am working with the [sakila database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7go2.png) and I need to write a query to find out all the films that are available in the country Canada.

```
SELECT FILM_ID AS Film_id, TITLE AS Title 
FROM FILM
WHERE COUNTRY IN ( SELECT COUNTRY
                   FROM COUNTRY 
                   INNER JOIN CITY USING (COUNTRY_ID)
                   INNER JOIN ADDRESS USING (CITY_ID)
                   INNER JOIN STORE USING (ADDRESS_ID)
                   INNER JOIN INVENTORY USING (STORE_ID)
                   INNER JOIN FILM USING (FILM_ID)
                   WHERE COUNTRY = 'Canada')
ORDER BY Title ;
```

When I try to run the above-written query, I am getting an Error 1054, unknown column 'country' in 'IN/ALL/ANY' Subquery.

I tried rewriting the entire query to ensure that I'm not getting this error because of invisible garbage characters (I don't know what invisible garbage characters in queries are, I read a stack overflow answer for a similar type of an error) and even after that, it doesn't work.

Am I getting this error because of the numerous join clauses in the subquery or is that fine? Is there a more efficient way to write this query?

Please let me know what is wrong with this query and do tell what are invisible garbage characters in queries.

Comment: Based on the database structure, I don't think you can answer this question because the film table does not have any indications where the film was released. The database structure does have an address table with a country element, but the address is associated with the store where the rental film is available, not with the film table. Btw, there is no country field in the film table and you probably need to reference to the country field as country.country in the subquery to avoid confusion with the table name.

Comment: Why are you doing all these inner joins in a subselect?

Comment: Should I do it in the where statement in the main query instead? What would be a better way to look at this query? @tadman

Comment: Yes, Even I've felt this database structure isn't sufficient for the questions we ask of it. But the implication over here is fetching all the films that is available in Canada and that can only be done by filtering it using the country table. @Shadow

Comment: In this case I suggest you to update the question with the new business task description because your question as it stands does not make any sense. Also, pls follow this guidance to improve your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: This is the exact problem statement, "Suppose you are running an advertising campaign in Canada for which you need the film_ids and titles of all the films released in Canada. List the films in alphabetical order of their titles." @Shadow

Comment: Then this question cannot be answered. You can only list the films that are available for rent in a store in Canada.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. Why am I getting Error 1054 and how else can I approach this problem?

Comment: Usually these sorts of queries can be re-written by folding the subselect into the top level as one more JOIN operation.