# Selecting Distinct field and row num just to display an id number gives duplicated data

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, rownum

I have a table application and it has 10 columns. category is one column and this column has duplicated values. To get distinct values I have a query

`SELECT distinct(CATEGORY) as CategoryName FROM APPLICATION where applicationId=?`.

I am getting result without any issue. Here now I wanted to add a another column as categoryId. There is no such field,  I have to generate one. I tried with below query.

```
SELECT distinct(CATEGORY) as CategoryName , rownum as categoryId FROM APPLICATION where applicationId=?
```

Then it shows duplicate category with the rownum as id. I am ok with any number as id but category name should not duplicated. Can any one suggests how to do it in a single query.

Comment: if the rownnum is different , then definitely it will be duplicated

Comment: instead of rownum any function that returns some numbers for each row?

Comment: maybe you add the sum of the row number and then group by category ?

Comment: something like SELECT distinct(CATEGORY) as CategoryName, sum(rownum) FROM APPLICATION WHERE  applicationId=?
GROUP BY CATEGORY

Comment: Last query worked fine, Please update this as answer.

Comment: done please mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use

```
SELECT CATEGORY as CategoryName, sum(rownum) FROM APPLICATION WHERE applicationId=? GROUP BY CATEGORY
```

Comment: Thanks Alaa. This is working fine in sqlplus but when I use in the program it gives below error "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression". Any idea what may be the reason ?

Comment: My mistake forgot to add sum.

Comment: DISTINCT is not required in the query.

Comment: Why would anyone upvote an answer that uses `select distinct` with `group by`?  The `select distinct` is totally redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the subquery as follows:

```
select CategoryName , rownum as categoryId from
(SELECT distinct(CATEGORY) as CategoryName FROM APPLICATION where applicationId=?)
```

You can also use the `analytical function` as follows:

```
SELECT distinct(CATEGORY) as CategoryName, 
       rank() over (order by CATEGORY) as categoryId 
  FROM APPLICATION where applicationId=?
```

**Example:**

I have the following data:

```
SQL> SELECT WRITER_ID, TWEET FROM TWEET;

 WRITER_ID TWEET
---------- -----
         1 T1
         1 T2

SQL>
```

See the output of both of the above query:

```
SQL> SELECT WRITER_ID, ROWNUM AS GENERATED_NUMBER FROM
  2  (SELECT DISTINCT WRITER_ID AS WRITER_ID FROM TWEET);

 WRITER_ID GENERATED_NUMBER
---------- ----------------
         1                1

SQL> SELECT DISTINCT ( WRITER_ID ),
  2                  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY WRITER_ID) AS GENERATED_NUMBER
  3    FROM TWEET;

 WRITER_ID GENERATED_NUMBER
---------- ----------------
         1                1
```

Now, Let me change my data

```
SQL> UPDATE TWEET
  2     SET
  3  WRITER_ID = 2
  4   WHERE ID = 101;

1 row updated.
```

Table data is changed:

```
SQL> SELECT WRITER_ID, TWEET FROM TWEET;

 WRITER_ID TWEET
---------- -----
         1 T1
         2 T2

SQL>
```

Lets see what is the result of the above queries now:

```
SQL> SELECT WRITER_ID, ROWNUM AS GENERATED_NUMBER FROM
  2  (SELECT DISTINCT WRITER_ID AS WRITER_ID FROM TWEET);

 WRITER_ID GENERATED_NUMBER
---------- ----------------
         1                1
         2                2

SQL> SELECT DISTINCT ( WRITER_ID ),
  2                  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY WRITER_ID) AS GENERATED_NUMBER
  3    FROM TWEET;

 WRITER_ID GENERATED_NUMBER
---------- ----------------
         2                2
         1                1
```

Comment: This will impact performance badly rt? Any other way to get some random numbers generated ?

Comment: `This will impact performance badly rt? ` --> **No**. By the way, You can also use the analytical function `RANK` as updated in the answer.

Comment: first query is not working for me. I will try second one and wil update.

Comment: First query is giving an error invalid identified category. Something is wrong there. But the second query is working but looks  too complicated for me. Alaa Mohammed's query is also working which looks simple for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CATEGORY) AS CategoryName, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CATEGORY) AS categoryId
FROM APPLICATION 
WHERE applications =?
```

Comment: This is not correct. DISTINCT inside the OVER clause will throw an error.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Tejash Can you take a look at my question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763449/why-am-i-getting-error-1054-for-this-query-is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-wr